# Matplotlib OSError after manual texlive install

Tags: texlive, python, matplotlib

After setting `matplotlib.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True` in Python, the `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig` command raises

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/my_name/cmr9
```

I believe this follows a manual TexLive installation following the procedure [suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/12136).

I am using the agg back-end.
Adding the directory containing TeXLive binaries to the PATH environment variable using `os.environ` did not solve the issue.

Comment: how have you added the maual TL to the system path?

Comment: @daleif: as suggested in the linked answer, I added `/opt/texbin` to the `PATH` environment variable in the `/etc/environment` file, and symlinked the TeXLive binary directory.